# onclick="alert('Hola!');window.close();"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

was wondering if anyone could help me figure this one out. This might sound like the easiest question ever. I'm just getting started with jQuery.

In the image below, is it possible to replace the "https:/ /jsfiddle.net/vh6ptcrd/" to a Custom Message?

[image]

```html
<div class="tile">
 <div class="img-bg"onclick="alert('This Click will take me to...');window.close();">
        <p>Click!</p>
 </div>
</div><!--.tile end -->
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not with `alert()` you could look into a modal dialog provided by a framework like Bootstrap

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it is not possible. I would suggest using something like "Sweet Alert": http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert

It's easy to implement and looks better than the vanilla alerts.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way for customizing the browser's alert box. Instead you can use one of the jquery notification plugins:

- [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
- [Notify.js](http://notifyjs.com/)
- [PNotify](http://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/#demos-simple)
- [Noty](http://ned.im/noty/#/about)
- ...